# Steam Proton set Windows compatibility mode

Tags: steam

Is it possible to set the Windows compatibility mode in Steam Proton for games like you can do in the Properties window in Windows for an executable?

This could be a fix for a game that I'm trying to get working.

Answer (score 0):

Closest thing would be changing the reported Windows version with winecfg, as discussed [here on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/9a5pm3/can_i_set_a_windows_version_in_steamplay_proton/):

`WINEPREFIX=/path/to/SteamLibrary/steamapps/compatdata/{appid}/pfx/ "/path/to/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Proton 3.7/dist/bin/wine64" winecfg`

Where `{appid}` is replaced with the unique [Steam appid](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/149837/how-do-i-find-the-id-for-a-game-on-steam) for the app/game you're trying to fix.

If it's using 32-bit Wine then replace `wine64` with `wine32` above. No idea if Proton uses `wine32`, but it is available and Steam itself is still 32-bit, so it's likely.